# Getting data back to a reactive form in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs

I have set myself the task of logging in, getting existing user details and then providing the user the ability to edit them.
I have an Angular 7 reactive form like this:

userdetails.page.ts

```
    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private currentuser: UserService,
    private router: Router ) {

     }

     ngOnInit() {
    // first we need to make sure the current user data is up to date.
      this.currentuser.getUserServer();
      //
        console.log('currentUser = ' + this.currentuser.data);


      this.userDetailsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        id: [this.currentuser.data.Id],
        email: [this.currentuser.data.Email],  // [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
        username: [this.currentuser.data.UserName],
        dateofbirth: [this.currentuser.data.DateOfBirth],
        title: [this.currentuser.data.Title],
        firstname: [this.currentuser.data.FirstName],
        middlename: [this.currentuser.data.MiddleName],
        lastname: [this.currentuser.data.LastName],
        displayname: [this.currentuser.data.DisplayName],
        fullname: [this.currentuser.data.FullName],
        detailscomplete: [this.currentuser.data.Id],
        password: [this.currentuser.data.Password], // [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]]
      });

  }
```

I am trying to keep things separated so have a user service and an API service. (But I am not sure if the API service is strictly necessary - or if it should just be part of userservice call?) The API service (function being used) is:

api.service.ts

```
  Get(endpoint: string) {
        const fullurl = this.ServerUrl + endpoint;
        return this.http.get(fullurl, {
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        });

  }
```

Which I understand returns an observable, and it is here where I am getting a bit stuck. The JSON object from the server also contains some irrelevant objects as well as the ones I need so I try to get just the items I want. The middle function has this:

user.service.ts

```
public data:  UserData;

getUserServer() {
  this.api.Get(this.api.GetUserDetailsEndPoint).subscribe(res => {
    console.log('Id from server = ' + res['Id']);
    this.data = {
    Id:           res['Id'],
    Email:        res['Email'],
    UserName:     res['UserName'],
    DateOfBirth:  res['DateOfBirth'],
    Title:        res['title'],
    FirstName:    res['FirstName'],
    MiddleName:   res['MddleName'],
    LastName:     res['LastName'],
    DisplayName:  res['DisplayName'],
    FullName:     res['FullName'],
    DetailsComplete: res['DetailsComplete'],
    Password:     res['Password']
    };
    console.log('This Data.Id = ' + this.data.Id)
  });
}
```

This works to the point of getting the data and the logging of the Id presents the correct information and the others are there too. (Last line above.) However, I feel I need to make `this.data` itself into an observable in order to get back to the form, where I should probably subscribe to it.

I tried defining it as
`observable<UserData>` and also `observable<IUserData>` (which is an interface rather than a class), but doing so breaks the assignment of the elements. I feel I am pretty close, but missing something basic.

Is this the correct approach? How do I get the returned data actually into the form? Then I guess putting it back to the server will follow a similar vein.

Comment: The service must not subscribe. And it must not store any data. It must **return** an Observable. The component can then call the service, get back the observable, subscribe to it, and, inside the callback passed to subscribe, access the data and populate the form. You need to understand that the whole point of observables is to be able to be notified, asynchronously, long after you've called the service, when the http response is finally available.

Comment: Yes, I do get that, it is the joining it up thing I am struggling with I guess. Not storing data in the service is a good tip and I am going to try ngFelixl's suggestion. Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your code does not work is because its async. The data won't log because the log is executed before the data arrives.

I suggest to create an empty form first, make sure the properties match exactly the properties in your data. Your approach is correct. In your **user.service.ts** switch the code to

```js
getUserServer(): Observable<UserData> {
  return this.http.get<UserData>(`pathToEndpoint`);
}
```

In your **userdetails.page.ts**

```js
constructor(private userService: UserService, ...) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    Id: [],
    ...
  });

  this.userService.getUserServer().subscribe(user => this.userForm.patchValue(user.data));
}
```

The *patchValue* function provided by the form patches all the key matches between your data and the form. It ignores properties that are not available in the form, and the other way around. You should consider renaming all the properties into lowerCamelCase.

A tip when you go on with RxJS: You will read almost everywhere that you need to unsubscribe from observables if you have subscribed to them. But that's just the half of the truth. If you are sure that the observable is going to complete, then you do not have to unsubscribe. `HttpClient`.get is designed to complete after it has emitted its first value, or to throw an error. Therefore you don't have to unsubscribe from it. But pay attention when you use subscriptions. You will understand more clearly if you read about operators like [take](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/take).

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try... so are you saying I shouldn't use the API service, I was trying to keep it tidy, having all the URL endpoints and access in one place.?

Comment: It is best to store the url endpoints as a string in the `environments` files under `src/environments/environment(.prod).ts`. This makes it also easy to test your application with a fake backend. Then you can import the environment with `import {environment} from './pathTo/environment.ts';` and access the properties with e.g. `environment.apiEndpoint`.

Comment: Maybe not the ´apiEndpoint´, but the ´apiUrl´ and then use `this.http.get<UserData>(environment.apiUrl + '/entity')`.

Comment: Thank you ngfelixl, marking as answer, this helped A LOT... I would ask though, what would I use then to process data on the way through... e.g. I notice that the date hasn't gone through be cause the value in the json is e.g. "1958-05-17T00:00:00" and the required format is "yyyy-MM-dd". ? Rgds Brett

Comment: @BrettJB you wouldn't use anything. Displaying dates in a specific format is not the responsibility of a service. It's the responsibility of the view. Use the date pipe in the view. Leave the data as it should be.